# iPhone MKMapView: set span/region value to show all pins on map

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on a project (platform iOS 7) in which i required current location with stores around 5km, so how to calculate the span/region value to display all stores with current location on map.

```
MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull; 
double inset; 
for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapVW.annotations) 
{
    MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate); 
    MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1); 
    zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect); 
    inset = -zoomRect.size.width * 20; 
} 
[mapVW setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectInset(zoomRect, inset, inset) animated:YES];
```

this is what I'm trying

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question a bit more please? Where exactly is the problem? What have you tried so far, what's working and what's not?

Comment: for example, from your current locations there are 5 grocery store within 5km , so what i want is to display all the stores with the current location.What i tried is below but the problem is every time i have to set current location from Xcode

Comment: MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;
    double inset;
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in mapVW.annotations)
    {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        inset = -zoomRect.size.width * 20;
    }
    [mapVW setVisibleMapRect:MKMapRectInset(zoomRect, inset, inset) animated:YES];
this is what I'm trying

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to the question (not in a comment).  What do you mean exactly by "every time i have to set current location from Xcode"?

Comment: I mean from debug area i have to set the current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what your exact issue is but the following may help:

- The calculation of the `inset` looks wrong.  It's setting the `inset` (padding on the sides) to *20 times the width of the whole zoom area*.  What you probably want is to set the `inset` to a small *fraction* of the entire width.  Maybe you meant `0.20` instead of `20.0`:

  ```
  inset = -zoomRect.size.width * 0.20;
  ```

  You also don't need to repeatedly set the `inset` inside the `for` loop since it only depends on the final `width`.  You can move the above line after the `for` loop before calling `setVisibleMapRect`.
- You mention some issue with the current location.  It's not clear what the issue is but maybe you mean that this zooming code doesn't include the current location?  If so, maybe the current location hasn't been determined yet when this code is called.  Try moving this code to (or also call it from) the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method.  Make sure `showsUserLocation` is `YES` and that the map view's `delegate` is set.

By the way: iOS 7 includes the new method `showAnnotations:animated:` which automatically determines the bounding rectangle for some given annotations and sets the map's visible region for you.  It doesn't let you specify a custom inset like you are doing (though the default isn't bad).  So instead of the above loop, you would do:

```
[mapVW showAnnotations:mapVW.annotations animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks it helps. The method you said makes the code light. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *anno_Arrr = mapview.annotations;
[mapview showAnnotations:anno_Arrr animated:YES];
```